# jQuery animation queues across multiple elements

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

This question is similar to [this one about animation queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461912/jquery-finish-one-animation-then-start-the-other-one), but the answers in that thread are very specific and not easily generalised.

In my web application, messages are reported back to the user (info boxes, errors & warnings, etc) by outputting a `div` with `class="alert"` eg:

```
<div class="alert">Login successful</div>
<div class="alert">You have new messages waiting</div>
```

There could be any number of alerts on a page, depending on what the user does.

What I'd like is to use a jQuery animation to show each of the alert boxes sequentially: once one animation ends, the next one begins.

The answers in that other question said to use a callback like:

```
$('#Div1').slideDown('fast', function(){
    $('#Div2').slideDown('fast');
});
```

except that won't work if there's an unknown number of divs to animate. Anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a solution, though I get a sneaking suspicion that someone who knows more about JS closures might have a few pointers for me.

```
nextAnim($('.alert'));

function nextAnim($alerts) {
    $alerts
        .eq(0)    // get the first element
        .show("slow",
            function() {
                nextAnim($alerts.slice(1));  // slice off the first element
            }
        )
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easy enough to set up:

```
// Hide all alert DIVs, then show them one at a time
$(function()
{
   var alerts = $(".alert").hide();
   var currentAlert = 0;
   function nextAlert()
   {
      alerts.eq(currentAlert).slideDown('fast', nextAlert);
      ++currentAlert;
   }
   nextAlert();
});
```

You could probably make a simple plugin method out of this if it's something you'll be using a lot.