# How to make accordion menu close and open sequentially rather than simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery plug-in to generate accordion-like menus. However, my `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` functions seem to be happening simultaneously.

Ideally, I would like all expanded sub-menus to slide up, and then the selected menu item's sub-menu slide down once that's completed. My code is as follows:

```
jQuery.fn.accordionMenu = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $('#menu ul').hide(); // hide all unordered lists
        $('#menu li.selected ul').show(); // drop down selected item's sub-menu
        $('#menu li a').click(function() {
            var speed = 'fast';
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
                if (!checkElement.is(':visible')) {
                    $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('slow').parent().removeClass('open');
                    checkElement.slideDown('slow').parent().addClass('open');
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Solved with the following:

```
jQuery.fn.accordionMenu = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $('#menu ul').hide(); // hide all unordered lists
        $('#menu li.selected ul').show(); // drop down selected item's sub-menu
        $('#menu li a').click(function() {
            var speed = 'fast';
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
                if (!checkElement.is(':visible')) {
                    $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp(speed, function() {
                        checkElement.slideDown(speed).parent().addClass('open');
                    }).parent().removeClass('open');
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animations for jQuery can be linked sequentially using the callbacks for the functions. So for example

```
$("#menu").slideUp("fast", function () {
    $("#menu2").slideUp("fast", function () {
        $("#menu3").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

This little snippet will roll up `#menu`, then roll up `#menu2`, and finally roll down `#menu3`

Check the documentation for some examples: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Also, this question might be of use: [jQuery animation queues across multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505434/jquery-animation-queues-across-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this using dynamic classes on the elements to flag them as being expanded or collapsed.  So, for example.

```
$("#menu ul").click( function() {  
  $("#expanded").slideUp( function() {
    $("#expanded").removeClass("expanded");
    $this.slideDown();
    $this.addClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

that probably won't work verbatim as I've not tested it, but it shows the principle.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using a dynamic class of "open", so I may further improve my plug-in above to utilize that approach. Thanks!