# jQuery Fade In LI item, fade out and delay(); next LI, fade in, fade out

Tags: jquery

I have a list that I would like to have fade in and out through each of the LI with a delay between showing the next li. I feel like I should be able to just iterate through the List, but am not getting it to loop. Something with index?

```
$('#content li').hide();
$('#content li').each(function(n){
$(this).delay().fadeIn('li').delay().fadeOut();
//how to I start over in the LI again? keep looping?
}
```

Thanks for any thoughts, ideas and/or help! I appreciate it.

Comment: Each element in jQuery has its own animation queue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505434/jquery-animation-queues-across-multiple-elements for how to tie a bunch of effects together. (So in your each function, you'd add each element to the alerts array.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some issues with your code

[fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) can take as parameters *duration, easing and a callback* function

So passing `li` does not do anything ..

You can use the callback to initiate the animation of the next `li` in line ..

like so

```
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay()
     .fadeIn()
     .delay()
     .fadeOut( 
               function(){ InOut( elem.next() ); }
             );
}
```

and the first time just do

```
$('#content li').hide();
InOut( $('#content li:first') );
```

**Demo :**

```js
// http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/
function InOut(elem) {
  elem.delay()
    .fadeIn()
    .delay()
    .fadeOut(
      function() {
        InOut(elem.next());
      }
    );
}

$(function() {
  $('#content li').hide();
  InOut($('#content li:first'));

});
```

```html
<!-- http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/ -->


<ul id="content">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the loop to go on forever then change the `fadeOut` with the callback to

```
.fadeOut(
          function(){
             if(elem.next().length > 0) // if there is a next element
               {InOut( elem.next() );} // use it
             else
               {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));} // if not, then use go back to the first sibling
                         
           }
         );
```

**Demo:**

```js
// http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/1/

function InOut(elem) {
  elem.delay()
    .fadeIn()
    .delay()
    .fadeOut(
      function() {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
          InOut(elem.next());
        } else {
          InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
        }

      }
    );
}

$(function() {
  $('#content li').hide();
  InOut($('#content li:first'));

});
```

```html
<!-- http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/S5Cjm/1/ -->

<ul id="content">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```