# How to run javascript functions located in one function sequentially?

Tags: javascript, function, timing, sequential

So I almost got this the way I want. I have `.animate( some stuff)` in the `dealone()` `dealonedealer()` functions. However, all the animations are happening at the same time since the function `dealCards()` doesn't care about waiting till one function is over before going to the next line and running that.

Is there a way that I can have each of these 5 lines inside the `dealcards()` function, run sequentially, instead of all at once? For example, hand1 gets a card and hand dealer waits to be dealt his card till hand 1 receives his, then hand dealer, and then hand card, then hand dealer, and then goes to `hitorstay()` function. Instead of them all running at once?

```
function dealCards() {
    hand1.cards = [dealone()];
    handD.cards = [dealonedealer()];
    hand1.cards.push(dealone());
    handD.cards.push(dealonedealer());
    hitOrStay();
}
```

edit: Or is there some way I can just put each line on a timer or something? Like hand1.cards = [dealone()]; should take 8 seconds, and then go to next line, should take/wait 8 seconds, then the next...

Comment: If code is asynchronous, promises are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript runs in a asynchronous way.. so each line will be executed instantly... regardless of whether last lins execution is completed or not... its not blocking.

You can use promise-defer like it is used in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention .animate() i would suggest using the complete / done option of animations ([Finish one animation then start the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461912/finish-one-animation-then-start-the-other-one))
Turns out there is already this thread that might be of use to you [Finish one animation then start the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461912/finish-one-animation-then-start-the-other-one) , though it seems like you will have to refactor your code.

Eitherways i think it would be better to refactor your code because it is always good for the animations to be async as i would not like the res of my page to be blocked while one element animates :D